# Review of apps don't show up!

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I wrote 3 reviews for an app, one of them showe up once and the others never did.  This app is almost useless and I feel that others should know that.  So why isn't my review appearing?  It's negative, but professional.

Comment: Has the review been input for more than three days? Sometimes I've seen an app not get any updates for a while due to the review process / whatever else Apple had programmed into the code for putting up a live review for world wide consumption.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, you can't make more than one review for one version of an app.
So if you tap the review button and you have already made a review, it will show the old review again and you can edit it.